# How to perform Keys ( read, write, delete,) on Google memory store of RedisCache using .net core

Tags: redis-cache, google-cloud-memorystore

How to perform Keys (read, write, delete,) on Google memory store of RedisCache using .net core

Answer (score 1):

The [Memorystore API](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Redis.V1/latest/index) is used to manage Memorystore instances (create , delete instances, etc). If you want to read, write, and delete data (key-value pairs) within the instance, you need to use a [Redis Client](https://redis.io/clients#c-sharp). There are many Redis Clients available for C#.

Answer (score 0):

I see an example for java here [1], which suggests that any library may be used to connect, there is nothing specific for it being on Google Cloud Platform.

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/memorystore/redis/src/main/java/com/example/redis/AppServletContextListener.java

Keep a lookout at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples,  for any future updates on .net.

In the meanwhile, https://github.com/beetlex-io/BeetleX.Redis is one such .net library listed on official Redis site https://redis.io/clients